# Getting only 100mb from isp and using 10 gigabit router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

My ISP gives me only 100mb download and 100mb upload speed.

I have Ubiquiti EdgeRouter with 10 Gigabit SFP+ port and bought a SFP+ Transceiver Module so i can make SFP+ to RJ45 connection ( i'm using cat7 network cables ).

My pc have a 10GbE Ethernet PCIe adapter from ASUS.

Let say i connect my RJ45 cable using the SFP+ Transceiver Module into the first SFP+ port of the router as wan.

And i also connect a second RJ45 cable with SFP+ Transceiver Module into the second port in the router as lan and connect that cable into my pc 10GbE Ethernet PCIe adapter.

Will that work so i get internet connection on my pc and if not why?

I'm asking this to be understand if this setup works or not before buying all this stuff. I know there might be better ways, but please explain to me if that is possible or not.

Comment: Hi John, Welcome to SuperUser! What you are asking may be possible, but there is no point. Your internet throughput will only ever be 100Mbit in either direction... and due to overheads, you'll get less than that anyway. You can easily use a Router with Gigabit ports with your Cat7 cables to give you the same end result...

Comment: Hi Stese and thank you! -  I thought router port's also maybe had to be backward compatibility in some way, becouse it says 10g on them, but on  the 10GbE Ethernet PCIe adapter from ASUS it says "Full Compatibility with current network standards, including 10/5/2.5/1Gbps and 100Mbps, for seamless backward compatibility"...so i ddid not understand if it was possible to use this small amount of 100mb throughput and  it will works.. or not

Comment: even if it's possible, your ISP would have to provide internet at that speed for you to actually benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would *work*, but it feels like a bit of a waste - assuming you have 2 SFP ports (it's the edgerouter pro then) - you'd be *significantly* better off using a gigabit port to wan.

Without other 10GbE devices, only communication between your PC and your router would be at that speed - if you had another 10GbE device, it could go into the other port and communication between them would be at 10GbE.

You'd be spending the cost of the SFP+ module for no real advantage using it to connect to the WAN.

I mean, you would get internet, but your connection to the outside world would be only as fast as your ISP, and the connection between PCs would only be as fast as the slowest link.

Assuming you already own the router , I'd recommend *not* putting the wan side on the SFP device, or getting 10GbE set up *unless* you had a specific use for it. 10GbE hardware *is* dropping in price, so waiting a bit would be a great idea.

For now, the smart money is on sticking with the common, standard GbE ports.

Comment: Tank you very much! - My confusion began because the 10GbE Ethernet PCIe adapter from ASUS says "Full Compatibility with current network standards, including 10/5/2.5/1Gbps and 100Mbps, for seamless backward compatibility", but the router port only says 10gb for SFP+... and i get only 100mb from ISP so i thought router port  maybe not  backward compatibility also??

Comment: @John: Keep in mind that link rate (at which two directly connected Ethernet ports communicate) is a **completely separate thing** from the maximum plan speed that your ISP provides. Each link is also independent from the rest, e.g. the ISP↔router and router↔PC connections can run at different rates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware of which link speed is actually used. Each Ethernet speed is really a completely new protocol that needs completely new transceivers. RJ45 ports on routers and switches are *usually* 10/100/1000 - that means the port has three separate transceivers and a way to switch between them.

*SFP modules do not always work this way* - you are expected to have the right module for the connection type. There may be some modules with 10/100/1000 ports but you can't assume they are all like this.

It sounds like the connection from your ISP is an Ethernet connection (with a cat7 cable and an RJ45 connector on the end). It's most likely a 100Mbps or 1000Mbps connection - it may be a 1000Mbps connection even if there is a 100Mbps limit further along the line. If you use an SFP+ transceiver designed for only 10Gbps, it isn't likely to work.